# Get remote address by SOCKET-identifier in a recv-hook

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I've installed a hook on the `recv`-function in Ws2_32.dll. Now, when `recv` is called, I want to get information about who sent the information. So I tried the following to get the remote address of the sender, but the address I get is always wrong and very unrealistic for the internet (e. g. I get 2.0.0.80).

What am I doing wrong?

```
int __stdcall TcpHook::my_recv(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)
{
    sockaddr addr;
    int len2 = sizeof(addr);
    getpeername(s, &addr, &len2);

    char *sender = inet_ntoa(*(in_addr*)&addr);
    // print out sender etc.

    return tcpHook.recvOriginal(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```

The interesting point is that I don't have any information despite of the passed `s` (type `SOCKET`).

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of `getpeername`. Also, we have no idea how you're hooking; you will get garbage if the hook isn't being executed in the process that owns the socket.

Comment: The hook, of course, is in the same process as the original socket. I don't check the result because this is a proof of concept. I know I should do it, but this is not the fault.

Comment: Check `ss_family` of the sockaddr, this may not be an IPv4 address

Comment: It is IPv4. I found an interesting answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114503/1433564 - see the comments. It seems the described situation matches my case which could explain why I'm getting wrong results.

Comment: Yes, that would happen if this is a connectionless socket.

Comment: Well, no. It's a TCP stream... damn.

Comment: You *can't* know that 'this is not the fault' *unless* you test the error code.

Comment: Everyone says everytime I should post a minimal code example that would run and compile and expresses the problem. That is exactly what I did...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution... I just failed.
The correct code is:

```
inet_ntoa((*(sockaddr_in*)&addr).sin_addr);
```

It works.

Comment: This depends on the `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr` being the same size. This happens to be true. Generally, you should use the right type of `addr` when calling `getpeername()`.